# Flex wrap chrome issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

I am having an issue with flex wrap. Evertyhting works fine in all browsers except chrome. https://www.boksleiden.nl/ Can't get the menu to align as it should. any advice?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding a snippet of your code for better results on this community

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your element with classes `.site-header-col-center.site-header-main-center` is behaving differently on Firefox and Chrome due to the height of the wrapping container being less than the space it needs (logo is bigger than the height set on the parent).
This is the problematic line:

```
.site-header.style13 .site-header-main {
    height: 70px;
}
```

Commenting it seems to solve the problem.